# CSS: How to make Blog Post Background Transparent - White/Light

Tags: css, post, background, blogger

I was wondering how to make the box background of my posts lighter.

So as you can see from the image (link below), the background is already transparent but it is really dark, is there any way I can make it lighter or even more transparent but without it being so dark.

I have already tried

```
.content-inner {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)!important;
}
```

and also

```
.content-inner {
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .25)!important;
}
```

but so far it has not worked and there has been no changes at all.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have structure -

```
<style>
#element1{
opacity:0.4;
}

#element2{
opacity:1 !important;
}
</style>

<div id="element1">
 Here is image1
    <div id="element2">
    Here is image2
    </div>
</div>
```

The second element will depend on the first..
'image2' have 'opacity:0.4'

You should separate them ->

```
<div id="element1">Here is image1</div>
<div id="element2">Here is image2</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this, can you please elaborate?